# Organize JSON from PHP Loop

Tags: php, json, loops

Good night, i have a file in JSON and I need to organize it by ticket, bringing their subjects from each ticket but I'm not able to do this loop. Can someone help me?
I have 25 of these tickets, here and an example of the structure.

```
[
  {
    "TicketID": 28890,
    "CategoryID": 57526,
    "CustomerID": 97979,
    "CustomerName": "Cox Workman",
    "CustomerEmail": "cox.workman@seges.com.br",
    "DateCreate": "2017-12-13 03:08:42",
    "DateUpdate": "2018-01-04 09:18:25",
    "Interactions": [
      {
        "Subject": "Without Subject",
        "Message": "I'm looking for men's shorts With side pockets 100 percent polyester.",
        "DateCreate": "2017-12-13 03:08:42",
        "Sender": "Customer"
      },
      {
        "Subject": "RE: Without Subject",
        "Message": "Hello! How are you? We don't have this model: / We have other models on the site, take a look.",
        "DateCreate": "2018-01-03 09:18:25",
        "Sender": "Expert"
      },
      {
        "Subject": "RE: Without Subject",
        "Message": "Thank you. GO shorts like with side pockets. Who made this model?",
        "DateCreate": "2018-01-04 09:18:25",
        "Sender": "Customer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "TicketID": 28891,
    "CategoryID": 46403,
    "CustomerID": 97974,
    "CustomerName": "Vilma Mcmahon",
    "CustomerEmail": "vilma.mcmahon@seges.com.br",
    "DateCreate": "2017-12-25 03:12:39",
    "DateUpdate": "2018-02-12 05:14:11",
    "Interactions": [
      {
        "Subject": "Complaint",
        "Message": "Good night! I bought a shoe for my daughter at the store, but it is staining the sock, see the photos; What can I do to not ruin all the socks ???",
        "DateCreate": "2017-12-25 03:12:39",
        "Sender": "Customer"
      },
      {
        "Subject": "RE: Complaint",
        "Message": "Good morning How are you? We hope so! Wow, a shame it happened with tennis ... In this case, there is a different warranty for 12 months, and to offer this guarantee, the brand defines that for cases of defects, the evaluation is done directly with them, to evaluate the defect and already issue the authorization code for the exchange. As soon as the code is issued, just go to the store with the product to exchange! ",
        "DateCreate": "2018-02-12 05:14:11",
        "Sender": "Expert"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Your going to have to include a lot more detail on what are trying to do. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?.

Comment: It looks like it's already organized by ticket.

Comment: I can bring the tickets, but I can't loop the Interactions, to show in my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$subjects = array();
$json = json_decode($input);
foreach($json as $ticket){
    print_r($ticket->Interactions);
    foreach($ticket->Interactions as $interaction){
        $subjects[] = $interaction->Subject;
    }
}
print_r($subjects);
```

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but `$subjects` there should contain all the subjects in every interactions of every ticket.

Comment: Please do use the green tick to mark the answer as correct and close the question. Happy coding :)